# Spring integration Java DSL : creating sftp inbound adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I want to create a flow using DSL. The flow is from the adapter, message will flow to channel.

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundFlow() {
        prepareSftpServer();

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(this.sftpSessionFactory).getId("SftpInboundAdapter")
                                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                                .remoteDirectory("sftpSource")
                                .regexFilter(".*\\.txt$")
                                .localFilenameExpression("#this.toUpperCase() + '.a'").localDirectory(file).channel(MessageChannels.queue("sftpInboundResultChannel"))
                                .get());

    }
```

Not sure of compilation error at getId() method . tried to convert from Java 8 lambda to Java 7

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add an `id` attribute for your component to register it with that bean name in the application context. You config must look like:

```
return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(this.sftpSessionFactory)
                                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                                .remoteDirectory("sftpSource")
                                .regexFilter(".*\\.txt$")
                                .localFilenameExpression("#this.toUpperCase() + '.a'")
                                .localDirectory(file),
                        new Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec>() {

                            @Override
                            public void accept(SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec e) {
                                e.id("SftpInboundAdapter");
                            }
                        })
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue("sftpInboundResultChannel"))
                .get();
```

There is no such a `getId(String)` method.

Yes I'll fix its JavaDocs eventuelly, but you are facing really *compilation* error, hence wrong language usage.

Comment: Hi Artem, I am able to get rid of compilation error and write the adapter, but not able to start the adapter by using test example for S FTP in spring integration DSL. Could you please provide any pointer to it.